# Show Dialog before opening the camera

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, popup, alert

I want to display a message before the camera opens.

Right now the user clicks a button and the message is displayed for 1 second and then the camera opens immediatly. Once i close the camera the dialog is still visible.

I want that the camera only opens after you click okay on the alert message and once you close the camera the message is not shown anymore.

```
//Button Picture
    cameraBtn.setOnClickListener {
        showDialog()
        pb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        startActivityForResult(receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(requireActivity()),REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA)
    }

   fun showDialog() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("The message here")
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done",
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton -> })
    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResults needs to be moved into the Dialog Positive button.  When you press the cameraBtn everything in that code block will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement what you have on your cameraBtn into the alert

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("The message here")
    
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done"){dialogInterface, which ->  
        pb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        startActivityForResult(receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(requireActivity()),REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA)
    }  

val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()
```

Comment: i am using dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.alert) to display an image in the alert and once i implement it, the buttons are not visible anymore. do you know why?

Comment: Since it's a custom view, also use a custom style on your setview, that may be another question